# MySQL: Selecting rows where 1 column is the same without knowing the value of that column?

Tags: mysql, database-design

With the following integer columns:
iid, pid, aid

I would end up with something like:

> 1,1,1
>   1,1,2
>   1,1,3
>   2,1,1
>   2,1,2
>   2,1,4

If I want to select iid where pid is 1 and aid is 1,2,3, what's the best way to get that? Doing a

`SELECT iid WHERE pid=1 and (aid=1 OR aid=2 OR aid=3)`

returns every row but the last one.

Is there a better table structure to use? pid is a row in another table that can have several values. This table gives me the iid, a master id for that row with certain values. There is no set number of values, though, so it seems like I need a 1 to many table, but trying to get that down to the 1 iid seems inefficient.

Comment: I don't understand. pid is 1 for every row, and aid is 1,2, or 3 for every row except the last one. Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If pid 1 was a 2x4 piece of wood, it would have attributes like type of wood, length, and treatment. So pid 1 is the 2x4, aid 1 is 10 feet in length, aid 2 is treated, aid 3 is maple, and aid 4 is oak. That would result in iid 1 being a 2x4 that is 10 feet in length, treated, and maple. And iid 2 would be a 2x4 that is 10 feet in length, treated, and oak.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your current table structure, you could do the following to select the iid you want.

```
SELECT 
     iid, pid, GROUP_CONCAT(aid) as grp 
FROM 
     test 
WHERE 
     pid = 1 
GROUP BY 
     pid, iid 
HAVING 
     grp = '1,2,3';

+------+------+-------+
| iid  | pid  | grp   |
+------+------+-------+
|    1 |    1 | 1,2,3 |
+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

With the group query you can see the AID attributes together grouped by PID and then IID.

```
SELECT iid, pid, GROUP_CONCAT(aid) as grp 
FROM test 
GROUP BY pid, iid;
+------+------+-------+
| iid  | pid  | grp   |
+------+------+-------+
|    1 |    1 | 1,2,3 |
|    2 |    1 | 1,2,4 |
+------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```